# What happens first, flat or % armor penetration?

Tags: league-of-legends

When I have both `The Black Cleaver` and `Last Whisper`, which will reduce the armor of my enemies first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the Reduction is as follows:

1. Armor reduction, flat
2. Armor reduction, percentage
3. Armor penetration, percentage
4. Armor penetration, flat

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_penetration)

The same goes for MPen

An example with BC/LW:

Garen with 100 Armor:

100 - 25%  = 75 Armor

75 - 40% =  45 Armor(Only you)

45 - 10 = 35 Armor(Only you)

So you will damage garen as if he had 35 armor while everyone else damages him for his 75 Armor.

Comment: @IbrahimApachi - Armor pen cannot take armor to negative; if armorpen > armor value, then it's simply treated as if the target has 0 armor.  Armor Reduction, however, *can* take armor into the negatives (thus multiplying the damage done).  This will rarely come up due to a number of factors: reduction is calculated first, reduction is rare, and armor tends to scale naturally on champions to a point beyond all sources of flat reduction.

Comment: Are you saying that armor pen can't take armor to negative, but magic pen CAN take armor into the negative?  I know that when I have sunfire cloak and armor pen, it doesn't more damage than it says to monsters in the jungle.

Comment: @dphil He said that Armor can't, and same goes for MR (which means that MR can't either)

Comment: My point is that MR can.  I'm 100% sure on this.  On my junglers, I have sunfire cloak deal more damage than it says on the item.

Comment: Keep in mind that your jungler item increases your damage dealt to minions by 30%. Aand that's quite a bit.

Comment: I suppose that's true.  Can't remember if it did this before I got the jungle items too or not.